# Storing PHP(/PHP-FPM/Apache)'s temporary-from-upload files in RAM rather than the filesystem (or encrypted only)?

Tags: php, security, apache, file-upload, temporary-files

### Original question

So the project I'm working on is deathly paranoid about file uploads.
In the scope of this question, I'm not using that term in regards to payloads; I'm talking *confidentiality*.

Programs can always crash and leave temporary files loafing around in the filesystem. That's normal. The *slightly* confidentiality-paranoid can write a cronjob that hits the temporary file folder every few minutes and deletes anything older than a few seconds prior to the cronjob call (not *everything*, simply because otherwise it might catch a file in process of being uploaded).

...unfortunately, we take this paranoid a step further:

Ideally, we'd love to never see temporary files from file uploads anywhere but in process-associated RAM.

**Is there a way to teach PHP to look for temporary file as blobs in memory rather than in the filesystem?** We use PHP-FPM as a CGI handler and Apache as our webserver, in case that makes it any easier. (Note also: 'Filesystem' is the keyword here, rather than 'disc', since there are of course ways to map the filesystem to RAM, but that doesn't fix the accessibility and automatic post-crash-clean-up issue.)

**Alternatively, is there a way these temporary files can be *encrypted* immediately when they're being written to disc**, so that they're never held in the file system without encryption?

---

### Thread overview

I can unfortunately only accept *one* answer - but to anyone reading this, the entire thread is *extremely* valuable and contains the collective insights of many people. Depending on what *you* are hoping to achieve, the accepted answer *may not be interesting to you*. If you've come here through a search engine, **please take a moment to read the whole thread**.

Here is a compilation of usecases as I see them for quick reference:

#### Re: PHP's temporary files

- RAM instead of disc (e.g. due to I/O concerns) → [RAMdisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701508/storing-php-php-fpm-apaches-temporary-from-upload-files-in-ram-rather-than-the/5702449#5702449)/comparable (*plasmid87*, *Joe Hopfgartner*)
- Immediate (per-filesystem-user) encryption → [encFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701508/storing-php-php-fpm-apaches-temporary-from-upload-files-in-ram-rather-than-the/5733277#5733277) (*ADW*) (+ [a gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701508/storing-php-php-fpm-apaches-temporary-from-upload-files-in-ram-rather-than-the/5879171#5879171) as per *Sander Marechal*)
- Secure file permissions → [restrictive native Linux permissions (optionally per **vhost**)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701508/storing-php-php-fpm-apaches-temporary-from-upload-files-in-ram-rather-than-the/5905221#5905221) (*Gilles*) or SELinux (see various comments)
- **Process-attached memory instead of filesystem (so a process crash removes the files)** (originally intended by the question)

  - don't let the file data reach PHP directly → [reverse-proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701508/storing-php-php-fpm-apaches-temporary-from-upload-files-in-ram-rather-than-the/5878263#5878263) (*Cal*)
  - disable PHP writing to the filesystem → [see PHP bug link in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701508/storing-php-php-fpm-apaches-temporary-from-upload-files-in-ram-rather-than-the/5867691#5867691) (*Stephan B*) or [run PHP in CGI mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701508/storing-php-php-fpm-apaches-temporary-from-upload-files-in-ram-rather-than-the/5877346#5877346) (*Phil Lello*)
  - write-only files → [`/dev/null` filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701508/storing-php-php-fpm-apaches-temporary-from-upload-files-in-ram-rather-than-the/5904618#5904618) (*Phil Lello*) (this is useful if you have access to the data as a stream *additionally* but cannot turn off the file-writing functionality that runs in parallel; whether PHP allows this is unclear)

#### Re: your files, post-upload

- storing in database instead of disc → [file encryption in a database HowTo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701508/storing-php-php-fpm-apaches-temporary-from-upload-files-in-ram-rather-than-the/5862044#5862044) (*Rook*)

Comment: Is there a way to teach PHP to look for temporary file as blobs in memory rather than in the filesystem? --> use tmpfs for the temp upload directory.

Comment: @Artefact2: The keyword is very much *filesystem* (see the rest of the paragraph you quoted). That wouldn't help me at all, I'm afraid.

Comment: Why no just secure the file system? Run your php/apache or whatever under a functional user id and allow that user id and only that user id access to the temp directory.

Comment: @James Anderson: I'd like something that's per-process or even per-request, not per-program. There are powerful per-program solutions (SELinux/EncFS/comparable), which, while not perfect, certainly mitigate the issue, and so that's definitely a step that'll be pursued, but it's still sub-optimal.

Comment: Whoever went through literally all answers and downvoted them (this is what it looks like right now, I apologise if I'm misjudging that), I upvoted some of the answers you downvoted and would really appreciate if you said why you downvoted them, so that I know why not to pursue that avenue.

Comment: How long does the non-file temporary blob in memory live? What are the size ranges for the non-file blobs? How many non-file blobs would exist at a given point in time? What is the maximum acceptable latency for non-file blob access? And not to make your problem harder but you have read [LestWe Remember: Cold Boot Attacks on Encryption Keys](http://citp.princeton.edu/pub/coldboot.pdf) right?

Comment: @this.josh: "How long does the non-file temporary blob in memory live?" Ideally only up to a second. This is a *temporary* file, if the process deals with it properly, it'll be moved elsewhere immediately, with the proper encryption.

Comment: @this.josh: "What are the size ranges for the non-file blobs?" Anything up to the maximum file upload limit, effectively, and with no limit on the amount of files, so a bit as if there were no limit. I'm told not to worry about that aspect, due to (amongst other things) hugelarge RAM and (allegedly) pretty good swapping behaviour.

Comment: @this.josh: "What is the maximum acceptable latency for non-file blob access?" I'd say 'it doesn't matter', but of course that's not true. It shouldn't noticably exceed harddisc access times (>150%, for a semi-arbitrary but probably decently accurate threshold), or the non-security chaps will probably [rightly!] start chewing me out for performance reasons.

Comment: @this.josh: "And not to make your problem harder but you have read LestWe Remember: Cold Boot Attacks on Encryption Keys right?" Nope, but I've heard of the phenomenom. It's not really super-relevant here, though, but thanks for the link. We want something that's attached to process lifetime, not computer uptime lifetime. So cold boot attacks are not in this question's scope (which isn't to say they aren't interesting, even for us, just... well, not in the scope of this question).

Comment: @this.josh: Thanks for the questions! ^_^

Comment: @pinkgothic: 'pretty good swapping behaviour' this means the RAM is being writen to the swap file, no issue there? If you really want the info to never hit disk they you will need a section of non-paged RAM.

Comment: @this.josh: No issue there at all. We're not looking to prevent things ever hitting the disc, we're looking to prevent it hitting the file system. Basically, the emphasis is very much on getting the file shackled to the process its uploaded to. So, uploading process dies, additional automatic removal of uploaded files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered putting a layer between the user and the web server? Using something like [perlbal](http://www.danga.com/perlbal/) with some custom code in front of the web server would allow you to intercept uploaded files before they are written anywhere, encrypt them, write them to a local ramdisk and then proxy the request on the the web server proper (with the filename and decryption key to the files).

If the PHP process crashes, the encrypted file is left around but can't be decrypted. No unencrypted data gets written to (ram)disk.

Comment: *Hawt*. Thank you, this is fairly close to what I initially envisioned as a solution, but couldn't for the life of me figure out how to do without writing something entirely from scratch. 'Reverse proxy' is the keyword I've not been thinking of. Much thanks for the Perlbal link!

Comment: A similar approach would be to use mod_ext_filter (provided with HTTPd). It's capable of sending the request body to a command-line program which then returns the (modified) body for further request processing. In the external program you could parse the request parts, generate a long encryption key (symmetric should be okay), encrypt the file content parts with it and add the encryption key as a request variable to the request body. In PHP you decrypt the uploaded files with that key. The files would still be stored on disc by PHP, but thy would be encrypted with a nearly random long key.

Comment: I accepted this as my answer because it's probably the most intuitive solution to my actual question. :) (I figured I'd split the accepting and the bounty because there are so many great and insightful answers here.) Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 4):

**CGI to the rescue!**

If you create a cgi-bin directory, and configure appropriately, you'll get the message via stdin (as far as I can tell, files aren't written to disk at all this way).

So, in your apache config add

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /var/www/<site-dir>/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/var/www/<site-dir>/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then write a CGI-mode PHP script to parse the post data. From my (limited) testing, no local files appear to be created. The sample dumps what it reads from stdin as well as the environment variables, to give you an idea of what's there to work with.

**Sample script** installed as /var/www//cgi-bin/test

```
#!/usr/bin/php
Content-type: text/html

<html><body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/cgi-bin/test" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
    <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
<pre>
<?
echo "\nRequest body\n\n";
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
while (($line = fgets($handle))) echo "$line";
fclose($handle);
echo "\n\n";
phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT);
echo "\n\n";
?>
</pre>
</body></html>
```

**Sample output**
This is the output (source) when I upload a plain-text file:

```
<html><body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/cgi-bin/test" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
        <!-- Name of input element determines name in $_FILES array -->
        Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
          <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
<pre>

Request body

-----------------------------19908123511077915841334811274
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"

30000
-----------------------------19908123511077915841334811274
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename="uploadtest.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

This is some sample text

-----------------------------19908123511077915841334811274--


phpinfo()

Environment

Variable => Value
HTTP_HOST => dev.squello.com
HTTP_USER_AGENT => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110323 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.16
HTTP_ACCEPT => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE => en-gb,en;q=0.5
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING => gzip,deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET => ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
HTTP_KEEP_ALIVE => 115
HTTP_CONNECTION => keep-alive
HTTP_REFERER => http://dev.squello.com/cgi-bin/test
CONTENT_TYPE => multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------19908123511077915841334811274
CONTENT_LENGTH => 376
PATH => /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
SERVER_SIGNATURE => <address>Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at dev.squello.com Port 80</address>

SERVER_SOFTWARE => Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
SERVER_NAME => dev.squello.com
SERVER_ADDR => 127.0.0.1
SERVER_PORT => 80
REMOTE_ADDR => 127.0.0.1
DOCUMENT_ROOT => /var/www/dev.squello.com/www
SERVER_ADMIN => webmaster@localhost
SCRIPT_FILENAME => /var/www/dev.squello.com/cgi-bin/test
REMOTE_PORT => 58012
GATEWAY_INTERFACE => CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL => HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD => POST
QUERY_STRING =>  
REQUEST_URI => /cgi-bin/test
SCRIPT_NAME => /cgi-bin/test


</pre>
</body></html>
```

Comment: o_O This sounds near-infinitely exciting if true. I'm not sure if CGI-mode PHP is an option for us (I suspect not), but this is a completely different avenue. Definitely have to look into this 'unusual' behaviour. Much thanks!

Comment: Presumably security constraints prevent you discussing the security constraints... if not, what would the object to CGI be?

Comment: I think I could probably dare to be that precise, actually! :) But I don't think I can go into that without it becoming a larger blurb. The most trivial and quickest to mention here is performance. Then I've been cited a number of security concerns with CGI handlers, none of which I know off the top of my head (not my area of expertise). But! You'll notice I haven't edited my question to disqualify CGI-PHP, and I don't intend to. It's the most elegant solution I currently see. (Whereas we'll probably patch PHP, which I wouldn't recommend to anyone else looking for an answer to this question.)

Comment: @downvoter Am I wrong about the no temporary files? I don't want this code causing security problems for anyone! (CGI security in general is out-of-scope)

Comment: +1 for the manual input processing.  Preventing PHP's automatic `$_FILES` array from being created is probably the *only* viable approach towards keeping the temp file off of the filesystem.

Comment: Phil, I loved both your answers, so I gave your most-upvoted one the bounty. Thank you so much for your insights! :) I didn't accept your answer(s) because I wanted to split accepting/bounty, see my comment at the accepted answer. I hope that's all right with you. There've been many brilliant answers to this question and it's tough to choose.

Answer (score 4):

I had a flash of inspiration on this: black-hole filesystems.

Essentially, this is a fake filesystem, where data never gets written, but all files exists, and have no content.

There's a [discussion on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/) about these, and [one answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/how-can-i-create-a-dev-null-like-blackhole-directory/9409#9409) involves a FUSE implementation of just this (quoted here):

> This isn't supported out-of-the-box on
>   any unix I know, but you can do pretty
>   much anything with
>   [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net).
>   There's at least [one implementation
>   of
>   nullfs¹](https://github.com/xrgtn/nullfs),
>   a filesystem where every file exists
>   and behaves like `/dev/null` (this
>   isn't the only implementation I've
>   ever seen).
>
> ¹  <sub>Not to be confused with the
>   [*BSD
>   nullfs](http://wiki-static.aydogan.net/nullfs),
>   which is analogous to
>   [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs/).</sub>

**I haven't had a chance to test this** *but* if you set the upload_tmp_dir to a black-hole location, the upload (would|should) never be written to disk, but still be available in [$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) (or php://input). If it works, it's better than patching PHP

Comment: While this is a possibility, if I understand the problem correctly, [it's not actually necessary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5905221).

Comment: If anyone tests this, please leave a comment to share the results - at the moment this is expected, but untested, behaviour

Comment: Wow! This sounds absolutely bizarre. Very nice train of thought. Has me balking right this instant, but I'm going to let this sit for a while and think about the ramifications. Much thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with PHP, so my answer won't map directly into a how-to, but I think you're laboring under some misconceptions about what protection various system features provide, which have led you to reject valid solutions in favor of solutions that have exactly the same security properties. From your comments, I gather you're running Linux; most of my answer applies to other unices, but not to other systems such as Windows.

As far as I can see, you're concerned about three attack scenarios:

1. The attacker gains physical access to the machine, shuts it down, pulls out the disk and read its contents to her leasure. (If the attacker can read your RAM, you've lost already.)
2. The attacker can run code as a user on the machine.
3. A bug in the CGI scripts allows a process to read temporary files created by other processes.

The first kind of attacker can read everything that's unencrypted on the disk, and nothing that's encrypted *with a key she doesn't have*.

What the second kind of attacker can do depends on whether she can run code as the same user that's running your CGI scripts.

If she can only run code as other users, then the tool to protect the files is **permissions**. You should have a directory that's mode 700 (= `drwx------`), i.e. only accessible by a user, and owned by the user running the CGI scripts. Other users won't be able to access the files under this directory. You don't need any additional encryption or other protection.

If she can run code as the CGI user (which, of course, includes running code as root), then you've lost already. You can see the memory of another process if you're running code as the same user — debuggers do it all the time! Under Linux, you can easily see it for yourself by [exploring `/proc/$pid/mem`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux). Compared with reading a file, reading a process's memory is a little more technically challenging, but security-wise, there's no difference.

Thus **having the data in files is not in itself a security problem**.

Let's now examine the third concern. The worry is that a bug in the CGI allows the attacker to **snoop on files but not to run arbitrary code**. This is related to a reliability issue − if the CGI process dies, it may leave temporary files behind. But it's more general: the file might be read by a concurrently-running script.

The best way to protect against this is indeed to avoid having the data stored in a file at all. This should be done at the level of PHP or its libraries, and I can't help with that. If it's not possible, then [**nullfs**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/how-can-i-create-a-dev-null-like-blackhole-directory) as [suggested by Phil Lello](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701508/storing-php-php-fpm-apaches-temporary-from-upload-files-in-ram-rather-than-the/5904618#5904618) is a reasonable workaround: the PHP process will be thinking it's writing data to a file, but the file will never actually contain any data.

There's another common unix trick which might be useful here: once you've created a file, you can **unlink** (remove) it and continue working with it. As soon as it's unlinked, the file can't be accessed by its former name, but the data remains in the filesystem as long as the file is open in at least one process. However, this is mostly useful for reliability, to get the OS to remove the data when the process dies for any reason. An attacker who can open arbitrary files with the process's permissions can access the data through `/proc/$pid/fd/$fd`. And an attacker who can open files at any time has a small window between the creation of the file and its unlinking: if she can open the file then, she can watch data that's added to it subsequently. This may nonetheless be useful protection, as it turns the attack into one that is time-sensitive and may require many concurrent connections, so could countered or at least made much more difficult by a connection rate limiter.

Comment: @Gilles +1 For a very good point about /proc/<PID>/mem. I largely agree here; however, when multiple teams with different responsibilities are involved, it is sometimes necessary to provide the _illusion_ of added security (even if it's a fudge to make marketing materials technically true) - I have no idea if that's true here. There's also a slim chance a process could open a temp file before it gets purged from disk, keeping it on-disk but off-directory; I can't immediately think of a similar way to lock data in memory.

Comment: @Phil: Oh, a process can open a file and immediately unlink it. But that's not for security (debugging features will still permit access to the file, and under Linux there's no `ptrace` required, you can go and read it in `/proc/$pid/fd`), it's so that the file will be reaped automatically if the process dies a messy death.

Comment: While I appreciate your concerns (they're very valid in general and very valuable in security in general), I'm afraid you do miss what I'm trying to achieve. The idea is to have the file be discarded the moment the process dies, without having to rely on an however clocked out-of-process cron job or other features that removes the file. In that, having the data in files *is* a security problem (albeit certainly not the only one, I agree) - they might persist much longer than ever necessary.

Comment: This is absolutely *regardless* to where they're stored (disc or RAM). I don't at all mind the disc part. I mind the out-of-process part. :)

Comment: @pinkgothic: Ah, I see. Then what you want is indeed to not get the data in the filesystem in the first place. Having the OS remove the file automatically is easy but not sufficient. Encryption wouldn't buy you anything, after all the PHP processes would have to have the key.

Comment: Good point about process-bound keys, though I'd think if they were to crash, they'd take the key with them - which is what we're trying to achieve. On the other hand, it does depend on how encryption is done... and the moment it's out of process (and a lot suggests it would have to be), we lose again. So that's definitely something I should be wary of. Thank you.

Comment: @Gilles I think you misunderstood; my point wasn't to unlink to hide the file, it's that there's a race-condition where it could be opened elsewhere before deletion by the 'owning' process

Comment: @Phil: I believe my last paragraph addresses that (unlinking doesn't work as a countermeasure, but can be a mitigation). What did I miss?

Comment: @Gilles Never mind, I missed your edit when I responded to the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using FUSE to create an encrypted directory which can only be accessed by a specific user?

http://www.arg0.net/encfs

The memory won't be associated with a specific process but the files will only be accessible to a specific user (the same one your web server runs as to be useful!) which might be enough?

Comment: "*the files will only be accessible to a specific user*" - this sounds like it's strongly related to what SELinux offers (see comments @ plasmid87's answer), and is definitely something we're going to pursue. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Note that encfs encrypts files on a file-by-file basis. It's not volume encryption. This still leaves metadata out in the open, though the actual file contents is encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

PHP will store uploaded files to the filesystem before your script has the chance to intercept the data php://input and $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA will be empty in this case (even when you set `file_uploads = Off`).

For small files, you could try to set `<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ...` but I did not succeed using this. I suggest you recompile php and comment out the part handling file-uploads like in this [Bug report](http://bugs.php.net/23765) (Comment by pollita@php.net).

Pro: No file uploads at all, Data in php://input
Con: Recompile, no Vendor support

Comment: Yeah, your first paragraph is exactly the problem I'm addressing. This is really a gem, though! Thank you for that bug report link! That grants some phenomenal insights. (I never thought re-routing things to php://input would be that 'easy'! Will have to play around with this a bit...)

Answer (score 0):

Your concerns are valid.   There are a few solutions to this problem.   One is to store the file in a database.  A NoSQL database like MongoDB or CouchDB are built to efficiently store files.  MySQL is another option and has advantages over NoSQL.  A relational database like MySQL makes it very easy to implant access control because you can relate the `files` and `users` table by a primary key.

In MySQL you can use the `longblob` datatype holds 2^32 bits or about ~500mb.   You can create a table that is memory resident by using the MEMORY engine: `CREATE TABLE files ENGINE=MEMORY ...`.  Further more.  MySQL does have encryption in the form of `aes_encrypt()` and `des_encrypt()` but they both use [ECB mode which is garbage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29).

```
$sensi_file=file_get_contents($_FILES['sensitive']['tmp_name']);
unlink($_FILES['sensitive']['tmp_name']);//delete the sensitive file. 
$sensi_file=mysql_real_escape_string($sensi_file);//Parametrized quires will also use this function so that should also be binary safe.
mysql_query("insert into files (file)values('$sensi_file')");
```

Just select out the file and use it just like you would `$sensi_file`.  Keep in mind that you are escaping the input to obtain he character literals and thus storing the raw binary.

Comment: This is some great stuff on file handling in general that I've never seen before, but... `$_FILES['sensitive']['tmp_name']` is my problem - the file is is already in the filesystem, PHP put it there. I don't want it to ever be there (at least unencrypted) in the first place. If the PHP process continues as it should, we're already handling the data as we'd like. In case of a crash, we rely on out of process clean-ups, though.

Comment: (I am almost entirely sure at this point that there is no better solution to this than 'use SELinux/comparable' or 'fork PHP' or 'don't use PHP', but I like to hope!)

Comment: @pinkgothic The behavior of File uploads is controlled by PHP and is written in C++.  I would advice against messing with the code directly although it is an option.   You could setup a small ram disk and set that as your destination for tmp uploaded files.

Comment: "*The behavior of File uploads is controlled by PHP and is written in C++.*" I'm aware. :) The RAM disk doesn't address the security issue, though. Still, thank you very much for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [`tmpfs`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) and mount it with a proper umask. That way, the only processes that can read files off it are the users who created it. And, because this is a `tmpfs`, nothing is ever stored on disk.

I would advise *against* ADW's `encfs` solution. Encfs does not encrypt volumes but it encrypts files on a file-by-file basis, still leaving a lot of metadata exposed.

Comment: '*nothing is ever stored on disk*' - the problem isn't disc, though, the problem is that it's in the filesystem. 'Proper umasks' would at best be a per-program (PHP/Apache) solution, whereas I'm looking for a per-request solution. But much thanks for the `encfs` heads-up! Appreciated.

Comment: Proper umask can also be a per-user solution. Just umask so that uploaded files belong to a specific user and have permissions 600 for example. Then let PHP-FPM handle that each vhost runs as a different user.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're thinking! We're not using multiple vhosts. This isn't a shared-server setup, it's a single high-security web-application. Confidentiality is for the end-user, so that if the system is compromised at any time, you don't end up having potentially important client files in the temporary file system.

Answer (score 0):

the most obvious approach would be:

- set up a ram disk - http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html
- configure upload_tmp_dir accordingly

i don't see any problems with that. just be sure you allocate enough space tough.

you can real time encrypt with LUKS or truecrypt

edit:

after your comment i think i now understand your problem

apache/php doesnt support this.

you can however write your own deamon, open a socket connection to listen on and handle incoming data in whatevery way you want. basically writing your own webserver in php.
shouldnt be too much work. there are also some nice classes available. zend has some server libraries that faciliate http handling.

but you could do this far easier in perl. you can just file post data chunk by chunk in to process associated memory. php just has a different work flow.

Comment: No, RAMdisc and associated 'solutions' still are filesystem solutions. I don't want the file in the filesystem - I want it in process-associated memory, where a process crash will automatically remove it. In the filesystem (regardless whether it is mapped to disc or to RAM), a process crash would not automatically remove the file.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered creating a RAMdisk under Linux?

http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/Ramdisk/ramdisk.html

Since this will appear as a native file-system location, you need only point your PHP instance (assuming it has the correct permissions) at this location.

I'm not sure what the ramifications are if the disk fails, I would imagine the location would become unwritable or absent. There may be further ramifications surrounding performance and large files, but as this is not my area of expertise I cannot tell you much about that.

Hope this is of some help.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but... I'm afraid not. The issue I'm trying to address is unencrypted 'third-party process' access to the temporary files if the process crashes (or at all, really). RAMdisk, to my understanding, wouldn't fix that - the memory is associated with the filesystem, not the process. You've still got unencrypted temporary files, they're just not stored on disc. [You'll notice I use the word "filesystem" in my question, not "disc" - this is intentional.]

Comment: A footnote - the author of that introductory tutorial article indicates that when the RAMdisk is destroyed, there are no leftover artefacts. I would recommend purging your Apache logs, however, as these may contain access traces etc.

Comment: My apologies I didn't read the question thoroughly enough. It is possible to encrypt the files on the fly and store them in the temporary disk, but you might find your server suffers if you have a very high throughput. Would it be sufficient to use a combination of stringent file-system permissions and a security daemon (e.g., SELinux) to prevent access to any process / user aside from Apache + PHP?

Comment: We're looking into SELinux, actually, so that's definitely an option, but it's one of those things we'd rather not rely on as sole security measure for the temporary files. Encrypting files on the fly would be perfect, though - performance is not really our concern. How would one make PHP do that? (Sidenote, regarding your prior comment: Our logs are taken care of, but that's valuable advice to others, so thank you for putting that here.)

Comment: If you're using file upload through POST, by default your file will be written to disk (usually /tmp). My solution isn't completely "on-the-fly" (i.e., in process) but it might suit your needs. You could try modifying **upload_tmp_dir** (php.ini) to the location of your RAMdisk. Once this is done, put in a post-upload call to GPG. I'm sure there are a couple of SO posts on doing this, but for convenience here is a quick tutorial on doing it on devzone [link]http://devzone.zend.com/article/1265 This comes back to what I mentioned earlier about overhead and dependency on a system binary.

Comment: The downside of that is that the uploaded file is still unencryptedly written to the filesystem before it's encrypted. But thanks for the article link! :) It doesn't look like there's a way to get around PHP's behaviour without changing the PHP source code - so I suppose SELinux, cronjobs and post-upload encryption will have to, anyway. ^_^